# Meta question displays differently in Home and Questions

Tags: support, status-bydesign, questions

On the Home page of Physics Meta, the question “Why can I still no longer ask questions?” is attributed to user250478, but on the Questions page it is attributed to a user who uses his name. Why do these pages differ like this when displaying the same question? Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: In hindsight (i.e., after rob’s answer and comments), it‘s relevant that I have Questions set to Newest.

Comment: I understand now that this display difference is a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mine looks like this:

> [image: screenshot]

Note that user250478 recently *modified* the question, rather than asking it. This would be less confusing if you had enough site reputation to see their modification — they posted, edited, then deleted an answer.

Comment: That’s on the Home page, right? What does that question look like on your Questions page? If you see a named user, is it because the two pages use different attribution rules?

Comment: If I sort the Questions page by Newest, I see “asked” with the name of the asker. But if I sort by Active, then I see “modified” as I see on the home page.

Comment: OK, so I think the conclusion is that the attribution rules on the Active view of the Questions page are the same as on the Home page — they take into account deleted answers that I can’t see — but those for the Newest view are not the same as on the Home page because they take only the asker into account.